# C# SynML client

Tags: c#, asp.net, syncml, funambol

I am developing an ASP.NET + C# web site and i need a library or component to connect to a SyncML server (funambol server) to synchronize contacts between the web site and the SyncML server

I need it to be written in C# and to manage all the SyncML stuff (connecting to the server ,syncing my contacts to server and giving me the contacts sent from server

I found the Funambol to have many clients but all written in java and c++ , I am not experienced in converting them to C#

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a project on sourceforge

[SyncMLDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/syncmldotnet/?source=directory)

I have not tried it my-self